# Generic constraints with C# Expression<TDelegate> - Cannot implicitly convert Type

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, expression

I've started using C# Expression constructs, and I've got a question about how generics are applied in the following situation:

Consider I have a type `MyObject` which is a base class for many different types. Inside this class I have the following code:

```
// This is a String Indexer Expression, used to define the string indexer when the object is in a collection of MyObjects
public Expression<Func<MyObject, string, bool>> StringIndexExpression { get; private set;}


// I use this method in Set StringIndexExpression and T is a subtype of MyObject
protected void DefineStringIndexer<T>(Expression<T, string, bool>> expresson) where T : MyObject
{
    StringIndexExpression = expression;
}
```

This is how I use `DefineStringIndexer`:

```
public class MyBusinessObject : MyObject
{

   public string Name { get; set; }

   public MyBusinessObject() 
   {
       Name = "Test";
       DefineStringIndexer<MyBusinessObject>((item, value) => item.Name == value);
   }

}
```

However in the assignment inside `DefineStringIndexer` I get the compile error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   System.Linq.Expression.Expression< MyObject, string, bool > to
>   System.Linq.Expression.Expression < MyBusinessObject, string, bool >>

Can I use Generics with C# Expressions in this situation? I want to use T in DefineStringIndexer so I can avoid casting MyObject inside the lambda.

Comment: Your code won't work because .NET doesn't support covariance between mutable types. You could use a immutable type (but that probably wouldn't work for you!). You could try `DefineStringIndexer<MyObject>((item , value) => ((MyBusinessObject)item).Name == value);`.. that might work!

Comment: Alternatively you could make `MyObject` generic too and use `MyBusinessObject : MyObject<MyBusinessObject>` then make the type parameter for the `Expression` of type T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment will not work, because the `Func<MyBusinessObject,string,bool>` type is not assignment-compatible with `Func<MyObject,string,bool>`. However, the parameters of the two functors are compatible, so you can add a wrapper to make it work:

```
protected void DefineStringIndexer<T>(Func<T,string,bool> expresson) where T : MyObject {
    StringIndexExpression = (t,s) => expression(t, s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work better for you?

Edit: Added `<T>` to constraint - think you will need that :)

```
class MyObject<T>
{
    // This is a String Indexer Expression, used to define the string indexer when the object is in a collection of MyObjects 
    public Expression<Func<T, string, bool>> StringIndexExpression { get; private set;} 


    // I use this method in Set StringIndexExpression and T is a subtype of MyObject 
    protected void DefineStringIndexer<T>(Expression<T, string, bool>> expresson) 
        where T : MyObject<T> // Think you need this constraint to also have the generic param
    { 
        StringIndexExpression = expression; 
    } 
}
```

then:

```
public class MyBusinessObject : MyObject<MyBusinessObject>
{ 

   public string Name { get; set; } 

   public MyBusinessObject()  
   { 
       Name = "Test"; 
       DefineStringIndexer<MyBusinessObject>((item, value) => item.Name == value); 
   } 

}
```